# Why quassar with ssr mode behave like a SPA

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

i have an ssr quasar app , when i lunch the website for the first time in chrome developer mode i see that the server return an html document.

but when i navigate to another page the server return only js scripts soo not rendering at the server side , it behave like a spa after the first page,

Is there any parameters i can change to render all the page at the server side ?

i read all the documentation regarding quasar ssr mode but couldn't find anything
and here is how the ssr config object looks like inside quasar.config.js

```
  ssr: {
   

      pwa: false,

  

      prodPort: 3000, // 

      middlewares: [
        'render', // keep this as last one
      ],
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Quasar is VueJS based, which (unlike e.g. PHP) focuses on delivering pages basically as SPAs, i.e. giving you data + JS to render it.

SSR only means that the first page is rendered on the server (e.g. for SEO purposes) and javascript takes over for fetching and rendering all subsequently loaded pages (or better the data + a recipe to render them) on the client. Thus, SSR will only get you server-side rendered pages upon initial load or page reload, all other renders are client-side.

You may learn about SSR, but also SSG (Static Site Generation), that might fit your needs, here: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html

Comment: is that the case  with nuxt3 also?

Comment: It is the same with NuxtJS, since it builds on VueJS and is in a sense just a higher order abstraction layer/framework that facilitates some common things that one frequently encounters when dealing with Vue. So take NuxtJS and Quasar like wrappers with a lot helper structures around VueJS. NuxtJS provides options to deploy the page via SSG as well: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/static-site-generation/ and https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#manual-pre-rendering

Comment: It is really a pity that Quasar is telling fairy tales about its SSR capabilities, although it is not really a SSR in the classical sense. The official Docs should render the truth instead of what they are telling right now. I came across this issue after spending much time in Quasar until I found out, that SSR is like SPA.

Comment: @itinance Quasar clearly stakes that SPA takes over once the first page has been returned to the client. That is the whole point. Reduce loading times by first sending a server-side rendered page then have Vue router take over from there for faster client-side routing. You can even have PWA takeover. This way, there is less load on your server as it only renders the first page a user requests, then just serves API requests for subsequent page loads from the same user.

Comment: SSR in JavaScript is where your server sends a HTML document at first then "hydrates" your app, which involves loading all the JS and making the page interactive. At this stage, SPA takes over. SSR doesn't change SPA functionality, it only improves initial loading times. If you want PHP/Laravel style server generated html, use templating engines like ejs, pug in your node js API.